# Error: KDC reply did not match expectations

Tags: linux, bash, sssd, realm

I was facing issues while joining a machine to domain using below command.
the server has OS as Almazon Linux 2 server which has to join to example.com.

I have done all the prerequisites which are required for Domain joining process for Li 
Below is the command i tried.

```
sudo realm join -U <username>@example.com dc01.example.com -v
```

O/P:

```
Could not get kerberos ticket: KDC reply did not match expectations
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have read some blogs & got to know simple mistake i was making:

Corrected command:

```
sudo realm join -U <username>@EXAMPLE.COM dc01.example.com -v
```

Using domain name in Capital letters resolved above error.

Comment: Why is this even a thing!? Case sensitivity like this is weird.